How do disable Elementor Dimension Control field
Is there any way to disable Elementor dimension control field. I want to disable any specific field in the dimension control. but I can not find any way to do it. Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks.
This is elementor Code.
$this->add_responsive_control(
            'margin',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__('Margin', 'textdomain'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::DIMENSIONS,
                'size_units' => ['px', '%', 'em', 'rem', 'custom'],
                'selectors' => [
                    '{{WRAPPER}} .your-class' => 'margin: {{TOP}}{{UNIT}} {{RIGHT}}{{UNIT}} {{BOTTOM}}{{UNIT}} {{LEFT}}{{UNIT}};',
                ],
            ]
        );



Not the best Code for the case but it works in this custom case i guess.
Put this code in your functions.php of the child-theme or main-theme:
add_action( 'elementor/editor/after_enqueue_styles', function () {
    ?>
    <style>
        .elementor-control-dimension .elementor-control-dimension::nth-child(2),
        .elementor-control-dimension .elementor-control-dimension::nth-child(3) {
            display: none!important;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
});


Thanks for your reply. But I think it will disable all of the 2nd and 3rd item for dimension control. So, after that, if I use another dimension, it will also disable the item. Is there any way to do it? That I remember previously in the Elementor there was this control in the Advance section. But Now I can not see it.
